# Experimental evidence for non-abelian anyons?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, specific-reference, topological-order, topological-insulators, anyons

Since [non-abelian anyons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon#Non-abelian_anyons) have become quite fashionable from the point of view of theory. I would like to know, whether there has actually been experimental confirmation of such objects.
If you could cite original literature, that would be great!

Comment: Original literature of what? Theory? Experiment?

Comment: Both please! Theoretical description of candidate systems and whether experimental progress has been made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know we do not yet have definitive verification of non-abelian statistics which would indicate the existence of non-abelian Anyons. The latest results I know about are the ones mentioned by akhmeteli and An, et. al. "Braiding of Abeliana and Non-Abelian Anyons in the Fractional Quantum Hall Effect." Arxiv:[1112.3400](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3400). However, I do not believe either are accepted as definitive proof.

You are correct in that there are other candidate systems proposed, such as $p+ip$ [superfluids](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.010506), [superconductors](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v73/i22/e220502), and [other systems](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v82/i13/e134521). Some good references and also a review seem to be given in these [review](http://iopscience.iop.org/0034-4885/75/7/076501/) [articles](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-conmatphys-030212-184337). As I understand it, the big push to observe evidence of Majorana fermions. [That](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/336/6084/1003.short) we do have some pretty good evidence for. Pairs of Majorana fermions are supposed to realize non-abelian statistics, but this has not yet been implemented and observed (to my knowledge).

As a final note, we do have evidence (see [here](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v98/i7/e076805) and [here](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v72/i7/e075342)) of abelian anyonic statistics, however I am under the impression that there may be some controversy about this.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2639 (Phys. Rev. Lett. 111, 186401 (2013)): "Magnetic field-tuned Aharonov-Bohm oscillations and evidence for non-Abelian anyons at v=5/2" , although I am not sure this is a definite evidence.

"We show that the resistance of the v=5/2 quantum Hall state, confined to an interferometer, oscillates with magnetic field consistent with an Ising-type non-Abelian state."

Comment: Thanks, but arent there also other candidate systems proposed? Could you also provide links for them, please?

Comment: "We stress that the presence of such a period is indicative of a non-Abelian nature of the ν = 5/2 state." Just an indication it seems...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have anything to add.